# SBCL - disable package lock at the beginning

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

How do I disable package lock at the beginning?
I was trying to put `(sb-ext:disable-package-locks sb-alien)` at the `.sbclrc`,
however, it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 5):

`sb-ext:disable-package-locks` is a declaration, to be used in a `declare`, `declaim`, or `proclaim` form. To turn of package locks for a given package, use `sb-ext:unlock-package`. http://sbcl.org/manual/#Package-Lock-Dictionary has the details.